# Changing <select>'s Background Color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I don't understand why the following isn't changing the select's background color.  It's probably something simple, but I can't see it.  I'm using Notepad++ editor with Chrome and Opera browsers.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Debugging</title>
    <style >
        select {
          background-color: #FF0000;
        }

    </style>
    <script>

      function myFunction() {
        document.getElementById('slct').style.backgroundColor = #FFFFFF;
      }

    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <select id="slct">
      <option>Choose</option>
      <option>The First Choice</option>
      <option>The Second Choice</option>
    </select>

    <input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="Click Me!">
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: add `""` between the color, it should be a string

Comment: I've wrote an answer that might explain your problems, please [Read Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47661054/713623)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check your browser's console, you might be getting errors. *Background-color* value must be in quotes.

```
document.getElementById('slct').style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
```